# Floating Social Icons on Wordpress Top panel

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am trying to float two css social icons facebook and linkedin on the top panel to the right of a wordpress website while making the icons responsive. I placed both icons into a container but it doesn't seem to control over the icons or even work.

You can find the site with the icons on the top right corner of the site half showing half hiding behind the menubar on the blue line at the top of the page.

http://www.rodgersgroupllc.com/newsite/

**Here is the HTML:**

```css
/* Social Icons */
#socialiconwrapper{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:right;
}
.social{
  float:right;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  text-align: right;
}
/* Wrapper */
.icon-button {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  height: 3.6rem;
  line-height: 3.6rem;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 3.6rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
/* Circle */
.icon-button div {
  border-radius: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 0;

}
.icon-button:hover div {
  width: 3.6rem;
  height: 3.6rem;
  border-radius: 3.6rem;
  margin: -1.8rem;
}
.twitter div {
  background-color: #4099ff;
}
.facebook div {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
/* Icons */
.icon-button i {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  height: 3.6rem;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 3.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3.6rem;
  z-index: 10;
}
.icon-button .icon-twitter {
  color: #4099ff;
}
.icon-button .icon-facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.icon-button:hover .icon-twitter,
.icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
```

```html
<div id='socialiconwrapper'>
    <div class ='social'>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/minimalmonkey" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i><span></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class ='social'>
      <a href="https://facebook.com" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i><span></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me why both of these icons are on top of each other and why this isn't working please?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, remove the padding and top margin from #socialiconwrapper.

```
#socialiconwrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.social {
   float: right;
   height: 36px;
   width: 36px;
}
```

Comment: That lined up the icons nicely http://www.rodgersgroupllc.com/newsite/ but the animation in the icons aren't working. See jfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/X3b5g/1065/ Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @FrankG. for hover effect used this css .`icon-button:hover i { color:white; }`

Comment: `.facebook div:hover{ border-radius: 50%; }` and remove the `.icon-button .icon-facebook` padding left and right and `.icon-button:hover div` height & width should be 3.3rem

Answer (score 2):

It's because of absolute potion of `.icon-button i`

Try this

```
#socialiconwrapper {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  margin: 1px 0 0;
  width: auto;
}
#socialiconwrapper .social {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
#socialiconwrapper .invert a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f3ad45;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
#socialiconwrapper i {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Milan Agheda that helped but now the icons don't animate. You can see how they animate here: http://jsfiddle.net/X3b5g/1065/ What could cause that now? Thanks!!